# How do I write a SQL query filter with an unless?

Tags: sql

I have a query that is returning transactions where the paycode and task do not match. However, there are a couple paycode/task combinations that can be ignored such as "Salary"/"SalaryReg".

Is there a way to write a query that goes like:

```
select user, trxdate, paycode, task from TABLE 
where paycode <> task 
--unless when paycode = "Salary" the task = "SalaryReg"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: No, the asker wants to exclude those rows from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user, trxdate, paycode, task from TABLE 
where paycode <> task 
and not
(
    (paycode = "Salary" AND task = "SalaryReg")
OR
    (paycode = "Janitorial" AND task = "Cleaning")
OR
    (paycode = "FrontDesk" AND task = "GreetingCustomers")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The query below will select all records from your table where `paycode <> task`, except when the `paycode` is `Salary` and the `task` is `SalaryReg`.

```
SELECT user,
       trxdate,
       paycode,
       task
FROM yourTable
WHERE paycode <> task AND
     (paycode <> "Salary" OR task <> "SalaryReg")   -- this condition only kicks in when
                                                    -- paycode = "Salary" AND
                                                    -- task = "SalaryReg"
```